# how to foreach the array in php?

Tags: php

when i print_r($a); the output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 3
            [vid] => 1
            [name] => cPanel
            [description] => 
            [format] => 
            [weight] => 0
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 4
            [vid] => 1
            [name] => whm
            [description] => 
            [format] => 
            [weight] => 0
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 5
            [vid] => 1
            [name] => test
            [description] => 
            [format] => 
            [weight] => 0
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

the array key maybe increment. now, i want to output all the `name'`s value of the array.
when i used the following code. it shows me an error.

```
foreach($a as $a->name){
    echo a->name;
}
```

Comment: Please *always* point out *what* error you are getting exactly.

Comment: Funny how this type of questions gets a bunch of answers practically before the posters submit has refreshed. Lol! :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
foreach($a as $object){
    echo $object->name;
}
```

Then read this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Doing:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "Array key: $key   Value: $value";
}
```

Will print out each value in an array and the name of the key.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
foreach($a as $value){
   echo $value->name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using -> is for objects; => is for arrays

```
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    echo $key . " " . $value;
}
```

Comment: True, but this is not what he wants to achieve (look at the sample data)

Answer (score 1):

The array contains a number of objects, but the `foreach` loop will work exactly the same way as for normal variables. The correct syntax is

```
foreach ($a as $object)
 echo $object->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical `foreach` syntax used a `key => value` pair.

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value)
{
 var_dump($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

> ```
> foreach($a as $value)
> echo $value['name'];
> ```

Comment: The key contains an object, though technically one could I suppose _maybe_ do this:

foreach($a as (array) $value){
echo $value['name'];} but I don't see the use and probably less efficient.